# SCOM Gateway command line arguments for non-domain installation

Tags: windows, scom

I need to install System Center Operations Manager Gateway in non-domain network. When I'm doing it manually it works but I need command line arguments for automation. SCOM Gateway package must be installed under local computer account without connecting to AD. I'm using the following arguments but some of these arguments are incorrect or missing. Arguments from [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456445%28v=sc.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is not suitable for my case since they are used for domain installation.

```
ADDLOCAL=MOMGateway 
MANAGEMENT_GROUP='{scom_group}'
ROOT_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_AD={scom_server_fqdn}
ROOT_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_DNS={scom_server_fqdn}
ACTIONS_USE_COMPUTER_ACCOUNT=1
ROOT_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT=5723
AcceptEndUserLicenseAgreement=1
```

Here's an example of arguments that I passed to installer during manual installation. Plus account type is Local.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVZ2g.png)

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me.

```
msiexec /i C:\Installfolder\MOMGateway.msi /qn /l*v C:\GatewayInstall.log ALLUSERS=1
ADDLOCAL=MOMGateway
MANAGEMENT_GROUP="<Management Group>"
IS_ROOT_HEALTH_SERVER=0
ROOT_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_AD=<Management Server FQDN>
ROOT_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_DNS=<Management Server FQDN>
ACTIONS_USE_COMPUTER_ACCOUNT=1
ROOT_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT=5723
AcceptEndUserLicenseAgreement=1
```

NB! Never put group name into single quotes. Only double quotes.